# Creating a table and exporting to LATEX

Tags: export, list-manipulation, latex, output-formatting

I have two functions as numeric[x, t] and exact[x, t].

I want to create a table including 5 columns as follows (table formatting doesn't matter) and to export it to LATEX:

[image]

**I use `TeXForm` or `ExportString[.., "TeX"]` but I can't get good results since the table includes exponential terms:**

```
\[Rho] = 0.5;
numeric[x_, t_] := 
 0.03125 (1 - 4 Sech[0.25 x]^2) + 
  0.0078125 t Sech[0.25 x]^4 Tanh[0.25 x] + 
  0.0078125 t Sech[0.25 x]^2 Tanh[0.25 x]^3 + 
  0.00012207 t^2 (-2.25 Sech[0.25 x]^4 + 2.25 Sech[0.25 x]^6 + 
     1. Sech[0.25 x]^8 + 4.5 Sech[0.25 x]^2 Tanh[0.25 x]^2 + 
     20.25 Sech[0.25 x]^4 Tanh[0.25 x]^2 - 
     22.5 Sech[0.25 x]^6 Tanh[0.25 x]^2 - 
     13.5 Sech[0.25 x]^2 Tanh[0.25 x]^4 - 
     16.5 Sech[0.25 x]^4 Tanh[0.25 x]^4 + 
     7. Sech[0.25 x]^2 Tanh[0.25 x]^6);
exact[x_, t_] := 
  1/8 \[Rho]^2 (1 - 4*Sech[\[Rho]/2 (x + 1/2 (\[Rho]^2)*t)]^2);
t1 := Table[numeric[x, t] - exact[x, t], {x, 0, 2, .5}, {t, 0, 2, .5}]
TeXForm[t1]
ExportString[t1, "TeX"]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `DecimalForm` to format your table:

```
\[Rho] = 0.5;
numeric[x_, t_] := 
  0.03125 (1 - 4 Sech[0.25 x]^2) + 
   0.0078125 t Sech[0.25 x]^4 Tanh[0.25 x] + 
   0.0078125 t Sech[0.25 x]^2 Tanh[0.25 x]^3 + 
   0.00012207 t^2 (-2.25 Sech[0.25 x]^4 + 2.25 Sech[0.25 x]^6 + 
      1. Sech[0.25 x]^8 + 4.5 Sech[0.25 x]^2 Tanh[0.25 x]^2 + 
      20.25 Sech[0.25 x]^4 Tanh[0.25 x]^2 - 
      22.5 Sech[0.25 x]^6 Tanh[0.25 x]^2 - 
      13.5 Sech[0.25 x]^2 Tanh[0.25 x]^4 - 
      16.5 Sech[0.25 x]^4 Tanh[0.25 x]^4 + 
      7. Sech[0.25 x]^2 Tanh[0.25 x]^6);
exact[x_, t_] := 1/8 \[Rho]^2 (1 - 4*Sech[\[Rho]/2 (x + 1/2 (\[Rho]^2)*t)]^2);
t1 = Table[ DecimalForm[numeric[x, t] - exact[x, t], {10, 9}],
           {x, 0, 2, .5}, {t, 0, 2, .5}]
TeXForm[t1]
```

```
(* 
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 0.000000000 & 0.000000005 & 0.000000079 &
   0.000000401 & 0.000001268 \\
 0.000000000 & 0.000000156 & 0.000001285 &
   0.000004448 & 0.000010807 \\
 0.000000000 & 0.000000269 & 0.000002173 &
   0.000007399 & 0.000017689 \\
 0.000000000 & 0.000000321 & 0.000002575 &
   0.000008702 & 0.000020650 \\
 0.000000000 & 0.000000313 & 0.000002495 &
   0.000008390 & 0.000019808 \\
\end{array}
\right)
*)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is an alternative but I still need an exponential form of the error for journal articles. Because I get sometimes very small errors such as 10^(-18). Decimal form is useless in this case.

Comment: Take a look at the `ExponentFunction` option of `NumberForm`.